# how to protect application files from being modified?

Tags: c#, setup-deployment

i have an windows application that i have made by visual studio 2008.this application uses some graphical files such as jpeg.i make a setup for this appreciation but i worry about such files being modified by client.would you please help me how to protect those files ?

Comment: Are those images compiled in resources?

Comment: i am not sure , how can i compile them into resources?

Comment: Can you tell us why you care if your client modifies the file? What's the big problem created if they do?

Comment: You can make it somewhat difficult for users to modify those files, but you cannot prevent modification. When files are on client computer he can do with them whatever he wants. Likewise I can modify Word.exe or System.dll on my machine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To detect such a tampering you should add your graphical files as resource within your application (or load from another assembly) and use [Strong-Name signing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4fa028b.aspx). Even if it is [not completely secure](http://www.offbyzero.com/resources/cas_broken), it should prevent the most ones from altering your resource files.

Comment: can this method protect app.config files ?

Comment: Strong-Name signing is not meant to protect a assembly from tampering, its meant to add another layer of identity to the assembly...

Comment: If you want to protest some content of app.config maybe it would be better to move that content somewhere else, e.g. hard code it, move it to database, ...

Answer (score 2):

You could embed the images into resource files that get included in the exe.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the images as a resource.

If you don't want to do that for any reason, then you could also calculate a cypher of the jpegs (maybe MD5) and check them against the one you previously stored in the code while loading the load program (form.load or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

You could [sign](http://www.fryan0911.com/2009/04/c-how-to-sign-and-verify-digital.html) your files this way no one would be able to change the files without having your certificate.

this might be overkill and it depends on how mutch security you want else just place the images as resources.